# How should I use getDatatypeProperty(String PropertyName) in Jena?

Tags: jena, ontology, owl

I have an owl ontology in which has a DatatypeProperty "hasAge"
Can anyone tell me why this code returns null value?

```
String URI = "http://owldl.com/ontologies/dl-safe.owl"
DatatypeProperty data = model.getDatatypeProperty(URI+"hasAge")
```

data is null!
Although this line exits in the owl file:

```
<!-- http://owldl.com/ontologies/dl-safe.owl#hasAge -->
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&dl-safe;hasAge"/>
```

This ontology works just fine with ObjectProperties. However, It does not seem to work with DatatypeProperties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `#` there.

`URI+"hasAge"` is going to be:

```
http://owldl.com/ontologies/dl-safe.owlhasAge
```

But as the comment indicates, the property's URI is:

```
http://owldl.com/ontologies/dl-safe.owl#hasAge
```

So change it to:

```
String URI = "http://owldl.com/ontologies/dl-safe.owl#";
```